# Avoid regex match if pattern has string before it

Tags: php, regex

I have these strings, and I want to match `b=(\d+)` only not `ab=(\d+)`. How do I do it?

```
"ab=10&b=20" -> 20
"b=20&ab=10" -> 20
"b=20" -> 20
"ab=10" -> no match
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `\b`, like:

```
\bb=(\d+)
```

Which matches only at a word boundary (between a `\w` and not a `\w`).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Really appreciate all other answers guys! Keep them coming.

Comment: Word Boundries, didnt think of that, smart.

Comment: I realized word boundaries in vim. Vim is just smart! :)

Comment: @Prasanth: Glad you got the issue resolved. But in future, please also mention the regex platform/engine you're working with (or you'll get some answers that use features that are not supported by your regex engine). In this case, you *could* update the question to include the tag `[vim]`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
/(?<!a)b=(\d+)/
```

Now this will match any number followed by `b=` **if not preceded by** the character `a`.

Test case:

```
$array = array(
    "ab=10&b=20",
    "b=20&ab=10",
    "b=20",
    "ab=10"
);

foreach ($array as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/(?<!a)b=(\d+)/', $str, $matches)) {
        echo $matches[1], PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "No match", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20
20
20
No match
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101156)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z])(?:b=(\d+))
```

`(?:[^a-zA-Z])`  It can not start with a-Z. You might want to change this, but you get the idea
`(?:b=(\d+))` I wrapped it in a group to make the regex combine it, `?:` makes sure `\\1` will still be `20`